# Keep file open, but don't lose data on crash

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter

I've got a bunch of log files in my app. I'm using StreamWriters to populate those.

The code looks like this:

```
try
{
    lock (fileLock)
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(GetTmpFileName(target), true))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(user.UserName);
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Obviously, from many points of view, this is a bad idea. But to me, it's critical not to loose the data when the app crashes.

Can anyone suggest to me a better way of doing this?

Comment: I am not really sure about your requirements, but you are using `using` block with `StreamWriter`, it will ensure proper disposal of the stream even in case of an exception.

Comment: Explain better *don't lose data*. You want to finish saving file or do not overwrite existing file (which you already do by using temp file) or what?

Comment: @Habib I think he's asking for a better way than reopening the stream for every message. Maybe the `AutoFlush` property is what is wanted?

Comment: The implementation I've got handles the "not loosing of data" correctly. But I want to be able to keep the data AND keep the file open. Closing and re-oppening the file takes too much time

Comment: Not being funny but if your app crashes, isn't that something you should fix in the first instance?

Comment: Hehe. Any app crashes. It's just a matter of time. I may need to update it and that requires a restart. Or server restarts. Or whatever. Over time, shit happens